# How to create a new PDF as new without changing the metadata?

Tags: c#, pdf, pdf-generation, xsl-fo, apache-fop

I have the original PDF file created by Apache FOP 1.0 with basic metadata added by Apache (producer, date of creation). I was editing the file and additional metadata appeared that I don't want to have (modify date and other). Is it possible to create a new file based on a file edited in such a way that there are no editing remains?

```
<?xpacket begin="﻿" id="W5M0MpCehiHzreSzNTczkc9d"?>
<x:xmpmeta xmlns:x="adobe:ns:meta/" x:xmptk="Adobe XMP Core 5.6-c016 91.163616, 2018/10/29-16:58:49        ">
   <rdf:RDF xmlns:rdf="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#">
      <rdf:Description rdf:about=""
            xmlns:pdf="http://ns.adobe.com/pdf/1.3/"
            xmlns:xmp="http://ns.adobe.com/xap/1.0/"
            xmlns:dc="http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/">
         <pdf:PDFVersion>1.4</pdf:PDFVersion>
         <pdf:Producer>Apache FOP Version 1.0</pdf:Producer>
         <xmp:CreateDate>2019-08-20T11:09:15+02:00</xmp:CreateDate>
         <xmp:CreatorTool>Apache FOP Version 1.0</xmp:CreatorTool>
         <xmp:MetadataDate>2019-08-20T11:09:15+02:00</xmp:MetadataDate>
         <dc:date>
            <rdf:Seq>
               <rdf:li>2019-08-20T11:09:15+02:00</rdf:li>
            </rdf:Seq>
         </dc:date>
      </rdf:Description>
   </rdf:RDF>
</x:xmpmeta>
<?xpacket end="w"?>
```

In addition to metadata, there is also the possibility of restoring the original version by removing the added lines in notepad ++ (which I do not want), i tried to replace the streams, but I fail (editing and new metadata are added to the file, they do not change the old text (incremental update?)). I would like the edited file to look like the original one made in Apache FOP 1.0. I tried to create XSL-FO with Word2FO.xsl, but I could not create a file with the same appearance as the original.

I can use a window application (Windows), console, website or something for C #, everything I've found so far either works badly or adds souvenirs after myself (watermark, change of producer, additional incremental update etc.).

Comment: *"adds souvenirs after myself (watermark, change of producer, additional incremental update etc.)"* - you usually get rid of watermarks by buying a license for the product in question.

Answer (score 0):

Our DynamicPDF Merger product allows you to merge the PDF without changing its contents. Also there are options to suppress the XMP metadata or set the producer as needed. 
Below is the C# code to merge a PDF, remove the XMP metadata (using the MergeOptions class) and setting the producer.

```
MergeOptions options = new MergeOptions();
options.XmpMetadata = false;
MergeDocument document = new MergeDocument(@"Source PDF file path", options);
document.Producer = "My producer";
document.Draw(@"path to save the output PDF");
```

You can refer to the documentation on the MergeOptions class here: http://docs.dynamicpdf.com/NET_Help_Library_19_08/DynamicPDF~ceTe.DynamicPDF.Merger.MergeOptions_members.html

A fully functional evaluation edition of the DynamicPDF Merger product is available on Nuget (Package ID: ceTe.DynamicPDF.CoreSuite.NET):
https://www.nuget.org/packages/ceTe.DynamicPDF.CoreSuite.NET/

More information and the option to download it from our site can be found here:
https://www.dynamicpdf.com/Merge-PDF-.NET.aspx